# Resizing plotlyOutput object

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I am trying to resize a plotlyOutput in a shiny app but changing the height parameters doesnt seem to affect the plot size, after updating today to R 3.4 and updating shiny, and plotly (plotly_4.7.0, ggplot2_2.2.1.9000, shiny_1.0.3  ) I realized that the size of the plot does not change dynamically when resizing the window. I have tried modifying the size of the plot directly using height in plotlyoutput, as well as modifying the $layout$height property from the plotly object,t but it doesnt seem to have any effect on the size of the plots.
Here is a sample code.

```
ui<-fluidPage(
mainPanel(
tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel("tab",
           selectInput("plot","Plot type",c("Box plot"="box","Inidividual cells"="cell","Violin plot"="violin"),"violin"),
           plotlyOutput('Barplot',height = "100px")
           )
    )
  )
)

server<- function(input,output,session){
output$Barplot <- renderPlotly({
bp <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=cyl,y=mpg,colour=cyl))+geom_point() 
bp<-plotly_build(bp)
bp$layout$width= 100
bp
})
}
shinyApp(server=server,ui=ui)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
plotlyOutput('Barplot')
```

and

```
bp <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=cyl,y=mpg,colour=cyl))+geom_point() 
ggplotly(bp, height=800) %>% layout(autosize=FALSE)
```

Comment: It runs fine, but changing the height value doesnt seem to have any effect on the plot

Comment: @JorgeKageyama For me it works. Did you remove `height="100px"` from `plotlyOutput` ?

Comment: I use R 3.3.3, and the same packages as you except that I use the development (Github) version of shiny.

Comment: I've just tried with R 3.4.0 and it works as well. Weird. I'm on Windows 7.